# Run-time error 1004. The selection is not valid, there are several possible reasons

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make dependent combobox in excel VBA, But I am getting the below error: I am not able to understand why I am getting. Help would be great.

[Run-time error '1004': The selection is not valid, There are several possible reasons:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITT3i.jpg)

### Code:

```
' @@subroutine to add values into comboBox drop down for type of Study
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastColumn As Long
'MsgBox "Value : " & Range("B4").End(xlUp).Select
'MsgBox "Sheet2" & Sheet2.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
'MsgBox "Test : " & Sheet5.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
  lastColumn = 18
  'Sheet5.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
  With Worksheets("Sheet5")

    For colsCounter = 1 To lastColumn
      With .Columns(colsCounter)
      lastRow = Sheet5.Cells(Rows.Count, colsCounter).End(xlUp).Row
        With Range(Cells(1, colsCounter), Cells(lastRow, colsCounter))
          Range(Cells(1, colsCounter), Cells(lastRow, colsCounter)).Select
          Selection.CreateNames Top:=True
          'Selection.CreateNames Top:=True, Left:=False, Bottom:=False, Right:=False
        End With
      End With
    Next colsCounter

  End With
  latLandingForm.cmbLSPList.RowSource = "LspList"
```

---

Comment: When you step through your VBA at what line does the error appear?  Your ROWS.COUNT, should that be .ROWS.COUNT?  Same with `WITH RANGE` may need to be `WITH .RANGE`  Wait, can you even nest WITH  statements?  You usually also want to avoid using the select function...tends to slow things down

Comment: @ForwardEd you can nest `With` blocks as long as the nested `With` is a child of the parent `With` `With sheet1: With .Range("A1"): .Value = 1: End WIth: End With` etc. (Which isn't the case in the OPs code)

Comment: @MacroMan, actually you can nest even if it's not a child. For example:`With ActiveCell: With Application: Debug.Print .Version: End With: End With`

Comment: @DougGlancy _whhaaaattt???_ Well that goes against everything I thought I knew!

Comment: @MacroMan, I'm not recommending it, mind you. :-)

Comment: @DougGlancy cheers! although it won't be today due to rep cap :( btw feel free to drop in the [vba lounge](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111528/vba-lounge) sometime ;)

Comment: @MacroMan : Thank you so much for your comments , I have found some other alternative solution for this issue. And it's working perfectly now. Thanks once again to you for instance response. cheers :-)

Comment: @Doug Glancy: Thanks to you as well for your nice advise.. :-) cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Your final `With` isn't correct. Try:

```
With Worksheets("Sheet5")
    For colsCounter = 1 To lastColumn
        With .Columns(colsCounter)
            lastRow = Sheet5.Cells(Sheet5.Rows.Count, colsCounter).End(xlUp).Row
            With .Range(.Cells(1, colsCounter), .Cells(lastRow, colsCounter))
                .CreateNames Top:=True
            End With
        End With
    Next
End With
```

You can only nest a `With` block if it is a child item of the previous block:

```
'// This will work fine
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    With .Range("A1")    '// Notice the '.' before Range()
        .Value = "test"
    End With
End With

'// This will not
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("A1").Value = "test"
    With Sheets("Sheet2")
        .Range("A1").Value = "test"
    End With
End With
```

In the second example, you would have to close the previous `With` block before starting with the next one.

Comment: tried implementing you suggested code, But seems it is not working.

Comment: @RanjeetKumar Not a very helpful comment - _what_ isn't working? _what_ error do you get? _what_ line does it occur on? Need to be more detailed.